# How to remove console errors relating to non-existent variables

Tags: swift, xcode, console

XCode, Swift and console output.

I have in my code changed variable names to more logical ones but the console shows errors saying the compiler cannot link to the previously named variables which are now gone.
How can I remove these references?

This is an example of the console output

2019-02-14 00:11:08.894679+0100 MyProject[3607:166878] Failed to connect (Flv1Button) outlet from (MyProject.ViewController) to (NSButton): missing setter or instance variable

The button Flv1Button doesn't exist now.

Comment: Aha, that's the way to do it , thank you.

Comment: The question remains though, can I undo it now?

Comment: The storyboard is correctly linked and it all works so presumably I'd have to change them back through the Refactor process and then do it again otherwise it sounds like I'd leave the old new names linked incorrectly. Rather seems to be asking for more trouble. Perhaps I should just copy storyboard and code to a new project and relink. It's not huge...

Comment: I had looked at that before but you don't see anything before you select something. Doh!

Comment: You got it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you’ll have to fix these manually. Just go to IB, select the view controller in question, and look at the “Connections inspector” tab in the “Inspectors” panel on the right and look for any outlet warnings indicated with ⚠️. You can delete any of those outlets by clicking on the ⨯ next to the outlet:

[image]

In the future, you might consider renaming `@IBOutlet` ivars by right clicking on them, choose “Refactor” » “Rename...”. That will update all references, including the storyboards.